# LAG on dates in a MERGE: inconsistent datatypes

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

nevermind what the purpose is of following example, it is just to show the problem.
follow statement works:

```
select 
    some_date, 
    lag(some_date,1,some_date) 
        over (order by some_date) prev_in_month, 
from test_table
where year_no = 2023 and month_no = 1
```

which gives following output:

```
| some_date | prev_in_month |
| --------- | ------------- |
| 1/01/2023 |     1/01/2023 |
| 2/01/2023 |     1/01/2023 |
| 3/01/2023 |     2/01/2023 |
etc
```

i've double checked and the some_date and prev_in_month columns are of type DATE.

following statement doesn't work:

```
merge into test_table
using (
  select 
    some_date, 
    lag(some_date,1,some_date) 
        over (order by some_date) prev_in_month, 
  from test_table
  where year_no = 2023 and month_no = 1
) source_table
on (test_table.some_date = source_table.some_date)
when matched then update
set test_table.prev_in_month = source_table.prev_in_month
```

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

The "some_date" in the third argument of LAG gets highlighted on error. when i put any number there i get the reverse error that a DATE is expected.
the statement does work if i convert the dates to a varchar representation and do lag on that, then wrap that in a "to_date".

EDITTED: made comments consistent with updated example, fixed update part

Comment: Works in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/psjcDxON) after correcting last line. What is the Oracle version?

Comment: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Comment: What does "effectively of type DATE" mean; and you said the "to_date" part is highlighted but you aren't using that function. You may have lost something important in changing this for posting. Please turn it into a [mre], including the actual data types you're working with.

Comment: excuse my, after simplying the example, that comment became inconsistent with the example. I editted it now.

Comment: Your `merge` works in 21c. In 18c throws mentioned error [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/llsUGKcE). I don't know WHY, looks like a bug. You can correct it easily like in the second merge.

Comment: Looks like bug 28749853, fixed with bug 30015265. There's a patch or a workaround if you have access to Oracle support; but if you do you could also apply the latest CPU.

Comment: Also you MERGE INTO test_table but your update statement SET ***source_table****.prev_in_month which is strange idea... the target of the update should be test_table...

Comment: oops! that is obviously an error in this example, though not the case in the real scenario.